# Display Panel in Widget Attach event in Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a tiny Firefox Addon which has a `Widget` and a `Panel`. I passed the `panel` object inside `widget` constructor.

`Panel` is getting displayed when I click on `Widget` object. However, when I call `panel.show([Widget Object])` in `onAttach`, it is giving me the error `anchor.ownerDocument not defined`.

If I call just `panel.show()`, it is showing the panel in the center of the browser window.

How can I set widget as panel's anchor in `onAttach` event?

If that is not possible, can I fire a `click` event on the widget so that `onClick` action happen and my panel comes up?

Comment: Why downvote after so many days? Moderators should look at this. Without reason a downvote should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `mainPanel.show()`,  use `view.panel = mainPanel;`:

```
myWidget = require('widget').Widget({
      id: "text-entry",
      label: "StrikeBase",
      contentURL: data.url("icon.png"),
//    panel: mainPanel,
      // Instead using this
      onClick: function(view) { 
//        mainPanel.show();
         // Instead using this              
          view.panel = mainPanel;
      }
});
```